# Python: numpy array sublist match with large list where sequence matter

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find in which index in the large list where it match with the sub list.

```
c = np.array(close)
EMA50 = np.array(MA50)
sublist = [False,True,True]
biglist = (c-EMA50)/c>0.01
>>>array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>sublist in biglist
>>>False
```

I expected True but it return False.

The desired output is

```
index_loc = [12,31,68,112]
```

Comment: @Divakar, I have make teh correction, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in` won't check for sub-arrays. Instead, it checks for elements.

You will have to do something like this:
(Using `A` for big array and `b` for sub-list for readability.)

```
n = len(b)
c = [i for i in xrange(len(A)-n+1) if (b==A[i:i+n]).all()]
```

`c` is the required list of indexes.

**Explanation:**
This is basic List Comprehension in python.
The idea is to create sub-arrays of the bigarray and check if it matches the sublist.

Breaking down the statement for better understanding:

```
c = []    
for i in xrange(len(A)-n+1):
    if (b==A[i:i+n]).all():    # if list and arrays match
        c.append(i)
```

Comment: @bkcollection, Added Explanation. Google about __list comprehension__.

Answer (score 2):

One very easy solution using the `sublist` pattern for [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) and checking for that signature and getting the indices would be -

```
np.flatnonzero(~a[:-2] & a[1:-1] & a[2:]) # a as data array
```

**Explanation**

Basically, we are slicing three slices out of the data array - One that starts at 0th index and goes until leaving out last two elements, another that starts at 1st index and ends at second last element and a third slice starting at 2nd  and goes on until the end. These three slices correspond to the three elements of matching required against the `sublist` pattern that's - `[False, True, True]`. We need to make sure that the first one is `False`, in other words, let's make sure the negation of it is `True`. Negation in NumPy is achieved through `~` operator. So, in essence, we get the combined mask off those three slices and get the corresponding indices with `np.flatnonzero`.

For the given data results in -

```
In [79]: np.flatnonzero(~a[:-2] & a[1:-1] & a[2:])
Out[79]: array([ 12,  31,  68, 112])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain further how it works? `np.flatnonzero(~a[:-2] & a[1:-1] & a[2:])`, what is `~a` mean,`~a[:2]` mean?

Comment: @bkcollection Added Explanation.